# Out-of-gas error on very simple contract function with lots of gas sent along

Tags: solidity, remix, address.transfer

My intention is to make a contract with a single function that takes a list of addresses van amounts and then transfers the amounts to the addresses.

I wanted to start simple and (using Remix) I have successfully compiled and deployed the following simple (right?) contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract Router
{

  function funRcv (address addr) public payable
  {
    if (addr != 0x0)
    {
        addr.transfer(msg.value);
    }
  }
}
```

I use Ganache as provider running locally.

I transferred 3 finney to it by executing (in the "Run" tab of Remix) the call to funRcv with the 0x00... address, which worked.

Then I set the value of the transaction to 2 finney, the gas limit to 3000000000 (!) and as argument to the funRvc function, I copy-pasted the address of my second default account from Ganache.

I expected the contract to transfer 2 finney from my first to my second default account, however, I get an "out of gas" error:

```
transact to Router.funRcv pending ... 
transact to Router.funRcv errored: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas
```

**Question:** What am I missing here, is my approach valid at all?

**Update:** I added the screenshot below to show what I mean, Remix issues the warning (bottom right) that it cannot estimate the gas and it gives me the "out of gas" error. Deploying the contract works, but calling funRcv (as described above) gives the "out of gas" error (even with so much gas sent along) ... ?!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I run your code and can't replicate the error.

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking a second to look into this. I added a scrfeen shot to make more clear what I see. When you compile that contract, do you not get the warning (bottom right)?